# How to Install GUI on Ubuntu server 15.10

Tags: server, apt, package-management, 15.10

I would like detail instructions on How to Install GUI on Ubuntu server 15.10

Answer (score 4):

Install the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

`ubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage; it does not provide anything (apart from docs) itself, but depends on all other necessary packages for GUI. So when you install `ubuntu-desktop`, `apt` will install all other necessary 
packages to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: Or `xubuntu-desktop`, or `kubuntu-desktop`, or `lubuntu-desktop`, etc...

Comment: or `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`